problemas con SQL 2019 al actualizar windows 10 a windows 11
Actualice mi windwos de 10 a 11 y estoy teniendo problemas con el SQL 2019, utilizo el visual studio para programar y mis aplicaciones que consumen consultas a veces tardan en ejecutarse, una consulta que me devuelve 1000 registros a veces se ejecuta en 1 segundo y otras tarda más de 30segundos.
En el SSMS también ocurre lo mismo si ejecuto esa consulta que utilizo en mis aplicaciones.
Ya he averiguado ese problema de los discos ssd PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity y esta en 4kb, lo más curioso de esto es que en windows 10 no hay problemas, simplemente actualice el windows y empezo este problema.
Si alguien tiene alguna idea de porque ocurre les agradezco la ayuda, lo molesto es que solo ocurre a veces.

Windows 11 tiene demasiados procesos extras corriendo de fondo, muchos no se actualizan por eso mismo.
